# How to reload DOM on ng-table refresh

Tags: angularjs, dom

I am using ng-table.
From one of my functionality, i am adding one new row(Configure Row) to the ng-table. It has different structure and data. So

I have one refresh button. If i click on that button. i need to refresh the ng-table that means, i need to delete newly added row(Configure Row).

If i reload the table, datas are getting refreshed and that New rom (DOM) is not deleting.

So that time i need to populate new DOM not only data.

```
$scope.tableParams.reload();
```

Comment: Please put code snippet and explain little more

Comment: How do you add this new row?

Comment: By seeing your issue, from array of table data on refresh button event remove particular item from array by using index. so here no need to populate new DOM